# php regex for namespaces containing no more than 1 dot

Tags: regex, netbeans

i have a bunch of calls in a repo of code like this:

```
$out = $this->call('myApp.Settings.Menus.something.doSomething', $input);
```

I'd like to find all instances of it using regex where the first param of `$this->call()` contains only 1 period.

i'm getting closer, i think, with this: `(?=\$this->call\(')(\.){1}(?=',)`

Why isn't it limited to 1 period?

Comment: How do you apply that regex (which engine, which flags, which anchors)?

Comment: i'm doing a regex code search in neatbeans, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, namespace will be in the first capture group:

```
\$this->call\('([^'.]*\.[^'.]*)',
```

If you want to use a lookbehind/lookahead so that the namespace is the only part of the string matched by the regex, you can use the following:

```
(?<=\$this->call\(')[^'.]*\.[^'.]*(?=',)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a simple:

```
 '[^.]+?[.][^.]+?'
```

Which means any number of non-dots, folled by a dot, and some non-dots again.

Better yet, be a bit more precise:

```
  '\w+?([.]\w+?)?'
```

This matches alphanumeric characters, and a dot. Second half `(`optional`)?`.

(Your `(\.){1}` would just match a single period.)

Comment: I'm trying to exclude results containing more than 1 dot.

Comment: Then make the second half `(` optional `)?` as well.

Comment: which part are you calling the second half?

Answer (score 0):

This is a safe regex:

```
\$this\s*\-\>\s*call\s*\(\s*[\'\"]\.[\'\"]
```

It accounts for whitespaces between language characters like:

```
$this ->   call ( '.'
```

where it is still technically correct syntax.  Additionally this is indifferent to single or double quoted string as teh first parameter.